# How to build guice-3.0-no_aop.jar from guice source

Tags: build-process, guice

Currently in our Android project, we're linking against guice-3.0-no_aop.jar for Guice. I need to do some timing measurement around injection, so I've check out the source code of Guice (git clone https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/), but don't know how to make the needed file. I've tried ant build with different options listed in build.xml (e.g. 'ant jar' or 'ant dist') but none of these produce the file.

So could anyone tell me how to build this jar from source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From google-guice groups:

If you want to use Ant:

```
ant no_aop<br>
cd build/no_aop<br>
ant jar<br>
cd ../..
```

and the no_aop flavour jar can be found under:

```
build/no_aop/build/dist/guice-snapshot.jar
```

ie. the tree under "build/no_aop" is just like the original tree, but has been 'munged' to remove AOP, so it still uses the original filenames for the binaries

If you want to use Maven:

```
mvn package
```

and the no_aop flavour jar can be found under:

```
core/target/guice-<version>-no_aop.jar
```

the difference with Maven is that the 'munging' is done as part of the main build, and the "no_aop" flavour jar is attached alongside the original jar